# Correctly syntax-highlighting javascript in phpstorm

Tags: javascript, laravel, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting, laravel-blade

In an existing laravel application I'm working on, .blade.php files contain a `body` section with my html and php in it. After the `body` section they contain a `custom_js` section which is used for inserting javascript code. In the parent template, the `custom_js` section is embedded like this:

```
<script>
@include('custom_js')
</script>
```

I can't get correct syntax highlighting in my .blade.php files for my javascript code. Php and html is highlighted correctly.
If I put the javascript code inside `<script>` tags the highlighting works fine and that's how the other developers have worked so far but before deployment you will have to remove these tags or else there would be 2 opening and 2 closing `<script>` tags. I don't feel comfortable with changing the parent template because that would cause enourmous refactoring effort.
I've already tried setting the Template Data Language of this specific file to various languages but that didn't help.

Is there an easy way or do I have to stick with inserting and removing `<script>` tags manually before deploying?

I'm using PhpStorm 8.0.3.

Comment: Where is your js code (that needs to be included) it located? Can you provide a sample simple file? I mean -- is it in another file together with other HTML/etc fragments .. or is it in separate file where only JS is present. If #1 -- nothing can be done unless you will do what @Frisbetarian suggesting you to do; if #2 -- then Template Data Languages should have helped here.

Comment: Are you sure you want to see the js code? i think that would just be noise and distract from the actual problem. It's valid and working. 
It's #1 and unfortunatly it really looks like there's nothing i can do. But there's still hope someone will come and solve this with some witch-magic.

Answer (score 1):

**The best solution would be**

...is to use comment-style language hinting - something like

```
// @lang JavaScript
someCode();
// @endlang
```

Something similar is described with language injecting, but I was not able to make this work in this manner :/ - I will update this if I do, I've started a separate question on the generic matter here:
 [How to set syntax highlighting to a code section to a specific language programatically/with comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58401451/1835470)

**Less prettier way**

...is to use Language injections directly - right click the code and click `Show context actions` (or Alt+Enter) => select `Inject language or reference` => select language of your choosing, although this does highlight the JavaScript, for me it damages the rest of the file's highlighting partially.

**Ugly, but generic working solution**

...is to trick PHPStorm in a way it thinks you are actually adding a `<script>` tag, but in fact you will comment it out.

```
{!! /* JS syntax highlighter !!}<script>{!! */'' !!}
var following = "javascript";
var doer = () => {
   console.log(following);
};
```

The trick is based of fact that `{!! X !!}` is actually converted to just `<?php echo X; ?>` - normally it's a tool for displaying text you don't want to be HTML-escaped.

So the code than becomes

```
<?php echo /* JS syntax highlighter; ?><script><?php echo */''; ?>
```

And in the end it just "echos" the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to yield custom_js in the parent blade view.

Like so: @yield('custom_js')

No need to wrap it in script tags.

Comment: But then i'd have to refactor the whole application to insert script tags in every child view. And as i said I was looking for an easier, non-destructive, way.

Comment: How do you expect Phpstorm to recognize the JS code without script tags?

Comment: I also don't see how removing the script tags from the parent view is going to cause immense overhead. It shouldn't take you more than 10 mins to go through the views and manually wrap your JS with script tags.

Comment: The solution really lies in not writing inline js. The whole point behind yielding custom js is to tailor each view with the scripts/plugins that it needs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86801/discussion-between-tobifasc-and-frisbetarian).

Comment: @Frisbetarian same way it recognizes HTML in `.blade.php` ... it's not impossible, they probably just didn't do it

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I'm really surprised phpstorm can't do the highlighting for you automatically -- in fact, I can't even find an option to force the syntax highlighting which is hugely disappointing since notepad++ can do it with 2 clicks.

My "solution" (it's ugly so I can hardly call it a solution) was to do this:

```
<script>

...some javascript...

</script>
@include("customJavascript")
<script>

...some javascript...

</script>
```

and then have open and close script tags in every included blade.php containing javascript fragments. This is really messy though, so I hope someone has a better solution for making code orderly.

Answer (score 0):

If it is still actual:

Just put the  tags into your custom_js file and put your code inside. PhpStorm will highlight everything correctly then.