# How to set syntax highlighting to a code section to a specific language programmatically/with comments?

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, syntax-highlighting, jetbrains-ide

I have a Laravel blade template (.blade.php) which contains plain JavaScript as a section that will be later inserted into a generic wrapper. So the example would be:

```
<div>Some HTML content</div>
@section('js')
var a = "b";
someCall();
@endsection
```

Now PhpStorm would recognize the JavaScript if it was in `<script>` tag, which it *can't* be. So I've tried this which I would expect to work like a section highlighter hint:

```
@section('js')
   // @lang JavaScript
   var a = "b";
   someCall();
   // @endlang
@endsection
```

and this

```
@section('js')
   // language=JavaScript
   var a = "b";
   someCall();
@endsection
```

But nothing worked (clickable language injection breaks other highlighting).

What am I doing wrong? How can I programmatically/commentarily set a section to be highlighted as a language I specify?

Answer (score 1):

It's not yet implemented for Blade (although exists for Smarty and Twig templates).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-29254 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

Comment: That is adding custom highlighter rules, which really is in some dev-state where one can't simply add regex that would cause some part be highlighted as certain language, I was thinking more like language 
 injection comments described here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-language-injections.html

Comment: Is you code located in a string or alike (HEREDOC/NOWDOC)? Nope. So you cannot use that Language Injection technique ... because it simply does not work like that.

Comment: So it is quite unusable in practice, that just blows my mind O.O

Comment: If only the custom injection rule worked out of the box - just providing the regexp with 1 group (as it is now, but actually does nothing because of the crazy internal calls field)